how to use google-play-scraper python script in mule 4
My requirement is to use the google play scraper script in mule4 using python script.
I am following this portal https://pypi.org/project/google-play-scraper/ to get the python script.
jython engine is configured in the application but not sure what else needs to be done to make it working.
Also is there any other way to make it work please let me know.
Error:
ImportError: No module named google_play_scraper in <script> at line number 1

I tried to configured below mentioned python.path in vm argument but no luck.
-Dpython.path=C:\Users\admin\Mule\workspace\mule4\google-scraper

-Dpython.path=C:\Users\dvastrak\Mule\workspace\mule4\google-scraper\target\classes

-Dpython.path=C:\Users\dvastrak\.m2\repository\org\python\jython-standalone\2.7.2

-Dpython.path=C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\arthurivanets\google-play-scraper

-Dpython.path=C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\arthurivanets\google-play-scraper

-Dpython.path=C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\arthurivanets\google-play-scraper\1.1.2

Code:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
        xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
        xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
        <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="e62d80d8-59a4-4a28-9d26-b11e4f8645db" >
            <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
        </http:listener-config>
        <flow name="google-scraperFlow" doc:id="92616144-5933-44f7-9f4f-1f573017fa39" >
            <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="e39a5d64-5ddc-4ee7-9164-d08de86816d8" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/test"/>
            <scripting:execute engine="python" doc:name="Execute" doc:id="b60f75f8-17e2-4dd2-bc39-5342a2b11f8c" target="aaaaa">
                <scripting:code ><![CDATA[from google_play_scraper import app

    result = app(
        'com.nianticlabs.pokemongo',
        lang='en', # defaults to 'en'
        country='us' # defaults to 'us'
    )
    print(result)]]></scripting:code>
            </scripting:execute>
            <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="3ade6953-97a6-41df-ab7f-c5e6c36b40a3" >
                <ee:message >
                    <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ---
    {
    }]]></ee:set-payload>
                </ee:message>
            </ee:transform>
        </flow>
    </mule>


pom.xml dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>


This question is similar to: ImportError: cannot import name create_string_buffer. See @HarshankBansal answer. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@aled the solution given there is not working. As per mentioned there i added -Dpython.path=C:\Users\admin.m2\repository\org\python\jython-standalone\2.7.2\jython-standalone-2.7.2.jar  but same error. Please try to execute the same and let me know if you find solution.

You should add the path to module google-play-scrapper to python.path, not the jar path.

@aled I tried add the below in vm argument but not worked for any of that. please give me where and what exactly i have to configure.
-Dpython.path=C:\Users\dvastrak\Mule\workspace\mule4\google-scraper
-Dpython.path=C:\Users\dvastrak.m2\repository\com\arthurivanets\google-play-scraper
-Dpython.path=C:\Users\dvastrak.m2\repository\com\arthurivanets\google-play-scraper
-Dpython.path=C:\Users\dvastrak.m2\repository\com\arthurivanets\google-play-scraper\1.1.2

The comment is not clear. [edit] the question to explain exactly what you did. Use [code block] format for code, configurations and logs.

@aled updated the question. please check.

Do you mean you added all of those at the same time?

@aled no. one by one
